# How do I call variables from a Java class into another Class?

Tags: java, mysql

I've read about inheritance or using the import. I just simply am unable to get the right answer. Firstly my code is of the following form:

```
class queries{
String query1="Select * from "+tableName+";
String query2="Select "+columnName+" from "+tableName+";
}
```

Now, I have another class where I wish to make make SQL queries using the queries mentioned in the queries class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


class test{

public static void main(String args[])throws SQLException
{

try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("This is Wrong");
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection connect = DriverManager
  .getConnection("SQLCONNECTION");
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect
  .prepareStatement(THIS SHOULD CALL query1 or query2);
 ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while (resultSet.next()) {
   System.out.println("THIS RUNS");
  //display text
}
preparedStatement.close();
connect.close();
}
}
```

So well, I need to figure out how to call query1 or query2 from the queries class in test. Sorry, but I hope someone can help me how to do this in a clean way. I can also create a Hashtable in queries where I call the respective query based on its name.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Also your code has no " used correctly. Do you know basics of Java? Ifyou don't, why you start with SQL things?

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. But well, it's essentially just showing what the value should be. When I say "SQL Connection" it does not mean actual SQL Connection, just "INSERT SQL CONNECTION HERE".

Comment: I mean, the SQL stuff and everything works fine. I essentially need to get the values of query1 and query2 from the test class. How do I do this?

Comment: So you need to instantiate class "queries", then access fields from object. Or make these fields static and access them from class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class queries
{
    public static String getQuery1(String tableName)
    {
        return "Select * from "+tableName;
    }

    public static String getQuery2(String tableName, String columnName)
    {
        return "Select "+columnName+" from "+tableName;
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
    connect.prepareStatement(queries.getQuery1("INSERT TABLE NAME HERE"));
```

Comment: It's better to use parametrized queries rather than creating statements with String concatenation.

Comment: Hey thanks, this is a great idea. Just to add to that. Could I possibly get the variables query1 and query2 into the Test class and then simply use them? Say if I specify tableName and columnName in the Test Class itself?

Comment: Try changing `class queries` to `public class queries`.